# how to prevent Out Of Memory because of many Runnables

Tags: java, out-of-memory, executorservice, runnable

I need to run 100 tasks. I want to run them in parallel, but only 10 simultaneously. I can use for it simple

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

then create 10 Runnables and sumbmit them to ExecutorService.

But what if there are 100_000 tasks or 100_000_000 tasks? At some point It would cause Out Of Memory because of so many Runnables in Memory.

So I wanted something like that: I store parameters of all task in database, then take another one of them from database when one thread became free and start new task with this parameters. I come up with something like this

```
package com.company;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    private static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

        private int i;  /* there would by actually parameters for task*/

        public MyRunnable(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println(i); // there would by actually some code
                Thread.sleep(1_000);   // there would by actually some code
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                executorService.execute(new MyRunnable(i + 10 /* there would by actually taking parameters from database for new task*/));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executorService.submit(new MyRunnable(i /* there would by actually taking parameters from database for new task*/));
        }
    }
}
```

Is it good or bad solution? What is the best solution?

Comment: Wait resp. Look into project loom.

Comment: @JoopEggen Given the title, the concern is running out of memory for instantiating a zillion `Runnable` objects. How does [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/loom/Main) address memory management of pending runnables?

Comment: @BasilBourque right, and thanks for providing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be concerned that too many pending `Runnable` task objects could take more memory than you will have available on your deployment machine. You want to avoid out-of-memory errors or virtual memory thrashing.

To avoid too many tasks, wait to instantiate the next task until the current one is done.

## End each task with submission of another task

Add a second duty to each instance of your `Runnable` objects: *Pull the next pending parameter from your database, and submit a task to the executor service.*

The task can be either a new instance of your `Runnable` implementation, or the task can be the same currently-executing `Runnable` instance. I prefer the first approach if the second approach would mean writing code to clean “dirty” state.

When no more input parameters remain, the last running instance of your `Runnable` simply completes, after shutting down the executor service. The executor service remains with no further work to be done.

Be sure to eventually shutdown your executor service. Otherwise its backing thread pool may continue running indefinitely, even after your app ends, like a zombie ‍♂️.

## Example code

### Task

Let's define a task that multiplies a number, then reports on the console.

This task’s constructor takes a thread-safe `Queue` of integers which it uses as input. Each task object draws one element, an `Integer` object, from that queue.

This task’s constructor also takes a reference to the existing `ExecutorService`. When this task finishes its work, it then instantiates another task. The old task submits the new task to that passed executor service. The executor service will execute the new task in the future, likely the very near future.

```java
package work.basil.example.bogus;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Multiplier implements Runnable
{
    private final Queue < Integer > queue;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public Multiplier ( final Queue < Integer > queue , final ExecutorService executorService )
    {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        try
        {
            this.doRun();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void doRun ( )
    {
        Integer input = queue.poll();
        if ( Objects.nonNull( input ) )  // If we have another input to process.
        {
            // Business logic.
            // Simulate doing much work by sleeping this thread.
            try { Thread.sleep( Duration.ofMillis( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 500 , 2_000 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
            int result = Math.multiplyExact( input , 2 );
            System.out.println( "INFO - input = " + input + " | result = " + result + " at " + Instant.now() );

            // Schedule another task.
            // Try to avoid needlessly submitting unnecessary tasks. But still may happen because of the interleaving of concurrent threads.
            if ( ! this.queue.isEmpty() )
            {
                Multiplier task = new Multiplier( this.queue , this.executorService );
                try { executorService.submit( task ); } catch ( RejectedExecutionException e ) { System.out.println( "e = " + e ); }
                System.out.println( "DEBUG - Submitted a subsequent task to executor service. " + Instant.now() );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### App

Let's write an app to run a few of those tasks.

This app instantiates an executor service backed by a thread pool of a certain size. The app instantiates and summits as many tasks as there are threads, to get the ball rolling.

From there, each executing task instantiates another task, then submits it for later execution.

This rolling work-instantiate-submit/work-instantiate-submit cycle continues until we exhaust the queue of inputs.

```java
package work.basil.example.bogus;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo starting. " + Instant.now() );

        final List < Integer > data = List.of( 10 , 20 , 30 , 40 , 50 , 60 , 70 );
        final Queue < Integer > queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue <>( data.size() , false , data );
        final int countThreads = 3;
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( countThreads );

        // Te get the ball rolling, start as many tasks as we have threads.
        // From there, those initial tasks will instantiate and submit further tasks.
        for ( int index = 0 ; index < countThreads ; index++ )
        {
            Multiplier task = new Multiplier( queue , executorService );
            try { executorService.submit( task ); } catch ( RejectedExecutionException e ) { System.out.println( "e = " + e ); }
        }

        Duration wait = Duration.ofSeconds( 20 );
        System.out.println( "DEBUG - Main thread will sleep for " + wait + " at " + Instant.now() );
        try { Thread.sleep( wait ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException( e ); }
        System.out.println( "DEBUG - Main thread waking after waiting " + wait + " at " + Instant.now() );

        executorService.close();
        if ( ! executorService.isTerminated() )
        {
            System.out.println( "ERROR - Executor service STILL not yet terminated after waiting for " + wait + " at " + Instant.now() );
        }

        System.out.println( "INFO - Demo ending. " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

### Execution

When run, we expect to see output similar to this:

```
INFO - Demo starting. 2023-02-23T05:51:19.584253Z
DEBUG - Main thread will sleep for PT20S at 2023-02-23T05:51:19.592739Z
INFO - input = 30 | result = 60 at 2023-02-23T05:51:20.542284Z
DEBUG - Submitted a subsequent task to executor service. 2023-02-23T05:51:20.549764Z
INFO - input = 20 | result = 40 at 2023-02-23T05:51:20.571571Z
DEBUG - Submitted a subsequent task to executor service. 2023-02-23T05:51:20.571752Z
INFO - input = 40 | result = 80 at 2023-02-23T05:51:21.180109Z
DEBUG - Submitted a subsequent task to executor service. 2023-02-23T05:51:21.180650Z
INFO - input = 10 | result = 20 at 2023-02-23T05:51:21.220425Z
DEBUG - Submitted a subsequent task to executor service. 2023-02-23T05:51:21.221124Z
INFO - input = 50 | result = 100 at 2023-02-23T05:51:21.753899Z
INFO - input = 70 | result = 140 at 2023-02-23T05:51:22.215306Z
INFO - input = 60 | result = 120 at 2023-02-23T05:51:23.023050Z
DEBUG - Main thread waking after waiting PT20S at 2023-02-23T05:51:39.588413Z
INFO - Demo ending. 2023-02-23T05:51:39.592896Z
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here:

- You can use a fixed length task queue. In this case, when the queue is full, the submit method blocks until a slot is released.
- You can store your tasks in a database as you mentionned
- You can use a messaging system such as JMS or Kafka with a persistently stored queue

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you are chasing ghosts.

Those tasks normally don't exist in isolation:

- there is something (another process, a user, a connection over the network) the causes the creation of new tasks
- the tasks need some finite time to execute
- normally there is also something that has an interest in the outcome of the task (if no one cares: why do you execute the task?)

Some problems are:

- if the something that causes task creation can do so faster than you can process the tasks then your system will sooner or later be overwhelmed with tasks - even a database has not unlimited capacity
- if every task needs only one second and you can handle 10 tasks parallel means that you need more than 100 days to process 100_000_000 tasks - if no other tasks arrive in the mean time. Even with 100_000 tasks you will need around 3 hours
- if you need 100 days to process the tasks: how can you make sure that your application can run this long uninterrupted?
- if every task needs only a few milliseconds then the round trip to the database could become your bottleneck

  - if a new task is created you then need to store that into the database
  - you need then to read that task from database
  - if the task is completed you need to remove it from the database
- what do you do with the results of the tasks?

  - Print them to the console? Who is going to read that?
  - store them in some file? This file is going to grow big very soon
  - store them in a database?
  - send them back over the network to the requester?

From the listed points you can see that the memory usage of all those task instances is only one of several related problems.